# Error after new nodejs deployment to ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Deploying a new version of my nodejs and react apps and running into an issue that I haven't seen before.

The deployment is happening via AWS code pipeline, and everything looks good there. However after the deployment I'm getting a Bad Gateway 502 error.

Upon looking in web.stdout.log, I see this repeated a number of times:

/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.js:35 #initializeTTLTracking() {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:16)

here is the full stack trace
[image: screenshot of web.stdout.log entry]

I found very limited info on this on the interwebs, but did find this post: https://pullanswer.com/questions/require-mysql2-breaks-npm-start

However, my scenario is different. I'm using Node 14, and version 3.1.2 of the mysql2 package. In the version of my app being deployed, I didn't change anything related to the version of mysql2 in package.json.

I can't reproduce the issue locally. I've tried reinstalling all my node modules and running my app, and it also doesn't appear.

The last working version of my app was 1.4.3, which was deployed on March 30. If I kick off a new build via CodePipeline pointed to the  1.4.3 release branch in GitHub, I get the same error.

If I go into ElasticBeanstalk and deploy the version that was built on March 30, everything works fine.

If you have any thoughts on how I can triage this issue, I would love to hear them.

Comment: node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index-cjs.js:5: this dependancy seems to have issue lru-cache if ur packaje json pulling latest change it to what it was in march

Comment: @tgkprog thank you for your reply. I don’t have a direct dependency on lru-cache in my app, it looks to me like the mysql2 module has that dependency. I’ve tried using the same mysql2 version in the new version of my app (which doesn’t work) as the old version of my app (which does work)

Comment: I faced the same issue with mysql2 `3.2.4`, but downgrading it to `2.3.3` solved the issue. `npm i mysql2@2.3.3`

Comment: thanks @Ahmadhassan, I'll try that. I'm curious why the issue happened in the first place since I was using the same mysql2 version in previous deployments without a problem.

Comment: this error occurs with latest mysql2 under node v12.x but not under node v18.x